# How does automated hotplug mounting work?

Tags: udev

I was reading a bit about gnome-mount, HAL, udev, etc. It left me with a couple of faint ideas how mounting a hotplug device might work in the latest Ubuntu release.

Could someone give a detailed explanation about what exactly is going on after a hotplug device (i.e. usb-stick) was plugged in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you should specify which part of the process is interesting to you but let's say a USB stick is added then...

- kernel detects and initializes the device (see `dmesg`), then exports all the information it has found via a directory in `/sys` (see `/sys/devices`)
- kernel sends a `uevent` signal which is picked up by `udev` daemon
- `udev` daemon gathers available info and checks config files in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and `/lib/udev/rules.d/` for rules about symlinks to create in `/dev`, permissions to set, programmes to run and sets some variables concerning the device (see `man udev`)
- `udisks` daemon in cooperation with `gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor` creates the appropriate directory in `/media` and mounts the new volume if deemed sensible
- `nautilus` checks the contents, creates thumbnails and opens a window if it is configured to do so; it also looks into `/media/*/autorun.inf` file for executable content

Comment: that was just what i was interested in. thanks a lot! so is gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor responsible for picking an appropriate driver for the device? i'm asking because i have a problem with an ntfs formatted usb drive that is always mounted using the ntfs kernel module instead of the ntfs-3g driver.

Comment: No, it is actually `udisks-daemon`, but I'm afraid it is not configurable (http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/7azSg34QulEtgOvRXE08) But you can use a `udev` rule to do that for you (haven't tried it myself) - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Mount_under_.2Fmedia.3B_use_partition_label_if_present.3B_ntfs-3g